# How can I use group in a LINQ expressions to group substrings of a field?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Following up for my workmate I have the following class:

```
public Pages {
  primary_key { get; set; }
}
```

Data for the primary key looks like this:

```
010000100001
010000100001
010000100001
010000100002
010000100002
010000100002
010000200003
010000200003
020000300004
020000300005
```

I am trying to understand how I can group this data using LINQ. What I need to do is to 
group by:

```
Column 1-2 (2 columns that I'll call subject)
Column 3-7 (5 columns that I'll call chapter)
Column 8-12 (5 columns that I'll call book)
```

Every time the subject changes I need to get a count of how many chapters and how many books are in that subject.

There was a suggestion link this. It gives me some ideas but I am still left confused.

```
from page in pages
group page by new { 
                    page.subjectId
                    , page.bookId
                    , page.chapterId 
                 } into group
select new {
             group.key.SubjectId
             , group.key.bookId
             , group.Key.chapterId
             , total = pages.sum(s => s.Page)
}
```

I tried to implement this as:

```
var a = from Page in rowData
    group /*Page*/ by new { 
       SubjectId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(0,2),
       chapterId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(2,6),
       bookId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(8)
    } into group
select new {
    group.key.SubjectId
    , group.key.bookId
    , group.Key.chapterId
    , total = rowData.sum(s => s.Page)
};
```

However I am getting an error message saying:

> Error  1   Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: What do you mean with the 'assumption that page exists'?

Comment: But you can fairly trivially convert your data into a matching page class using `.Select(key => new Page(key))` where the constructor splits up the string into the three properties. The Page class just needs to hold the three integers and provide getters for them. That's going to be a lot easier to work with than the combined key, but you can just substitute all the `page.subjectID` for `key.substring(0,2)` or `(key / 10000000000)`.

Comment: Wouter - There is no "page" class. The person helping made an assumption that there was one.

Comment: @RichardM: I suggested edits that look like they should satisfy your model (but because I don't have the rest of your code, I cannot be certain). At least, this shows how to fix the `Invalid anonymous type member` declarations. _The compiler was unable to 'automagically' detect a field name from the substring expressions_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you the idea:

```
new [] { 
    "010000100001", "010000100001", "010000100001", "010000100002",
    "010000100002", "010000100002", "010000200003", "010000200003",
    "020000300004", "020000300005" }
.GroupBy(s => new {
          Subject = s.Substring(0,2),
          Chapter = s.Substring(2,6),
          Book    = s.Substring(8) });
```

**Edit** See a demo live on **https://ideone.com/A6RQU**

Comment: I tried an implementation and updated the question. However it gives me an error message and I am not sure why. In this example rowData is a collection of Page classes and PartitionKey is the field I want to group by. I will mark your question as answered as I see it works but not exactly for my needs.